# Ncurses Pad locks up cursor

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to create a text editor in C using Ncurses. I am currently printing text to a pad which I can scroll through. However, when I execute `wdelch(pad)` the character expected is deleted, but then I cannot move the cursor.

Before `wdelch()` is called I call `wmove(pad)` so that the pads logical cursor is in the same position as the `stdscr` cursor and deletes the expected character. Strangely, if I hit delete again the cursor will update and move to the next location. From trying to debug the code it seems that wmove(pad) is the line that takes away cursor control.

Can you help me understand how to properly delete a character on a pad and retain the ability to move the cursor?

I think the problem must lie in my not fully understanding refresh and prefresh. Code is below and I truly appreciate any feedback.

The second set of switch statements, **case 127** is where the problem occurs. The refresh and prefresh happen at the beginning of the while loop. Thanks!

```
int main (int argc, char** argv){

int c, row, col, crow, ccol,prow,pcol;
// Program requires exactly one command line argument
if (argc != 2){
    printf("Please provide a file name argument only");
}

char* fileName = argv[1];   //get the file name from the command line
char str[150];
FILE* file = fopen(fileName,"r");
if ( file == NULL) {
    perror("");
    return(1);
}

char** text = textArray();  //create the array of pointers that will be used to store text info
int counter = 0;
//read text file contents into text array data structure
while (fgets(str,150,file))
{
    char* mem_allocation = (char*)malloc (150 * sizeof(char) );
    strcpy( mem_allocation,str);
    text[counter] = mem_allocation;
    counter++;
}
//set up ncurses screen ###########
initscr();
getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
raw();
noecho();
// create pad
WINDOW* pad;
pad = newpad (10000, col);
keypad(pad, TRUE);
int padMinRow =0,padMinCol = 0,padMaxRow = row - 2,padMaxCol = col - 2;
refresh();
wprintw(pad,"Team #4   \"%s\"",fileName);
prefresh(pad,0,0,0,0,padMaxRow,padMaxCol);
//#################################

//print text contents to screen
wmove(pad,0,0);
counter = 0;
while (text[counter] != NULL)
{
    waddstr(pad,text[counter]);
    counter++;
}
move(1,0);
prefresh(pad,padMinRow,padMinCol,1,0,padMaxRow,padMaxCol);
//0 is command mode
//1 is edit mode
//2 is exit with write
//3 is exit without write
int editorMode = 0;
while (1) {
    refresh();
    prefresh(pad,padMinRow,padMinCol,1,0,padMaxRow,padMaxCol);
    c = wgetch(pad);
    getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
    //mvprintw(row-1,0,"%d",crow);   //get ascii value of char
    if (editorMode == 0) {
        switch (c) {

            case 105:
                editorMode = 1;
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                mvprintw(row-1,0,"--Insert--");
                move(crow,ccol);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (crow > 1) {
                    move(crow-1,ccol);
                }
                else if (crow == 1) {
                    padMinRow--;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:

                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (crow < row - 2) {
                    move(crow+1,ccol);
                }
                else if (crow >= (row - 2)) {
                    padMinRow++;
                    prow = (crow - 1) + 1;
                }

                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (ccol > 0) {
                    move(crow,ccol-1);
                }
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (ccol < col-1) {
                    move(crow,ccol+1);
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                endwin();
                return 0;
                break;
        }

    }
    else if (editorMode == 1) {
        switch (c) {

            case 27: //ESC ascii code is 27
                editorMode = 0;
                move(row-1,0);
                clrtoeol();
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (crow > 1) {
                    move(crow-1,ccol);
                }
                else if (crow == 1) {
                    padMinRow--;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (crow < row - 2) {
                    move(crow+1,ccol);
                    prow = crow - 1;
                }
                else if (crow >= (row - 2)) {
                    padMinRow++;
                    prow = (crow - 1) + 1;
                }

                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (ccol > 0) {
                    move(crow,ccol-1);
                }
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                if (ccol < col-1) {
                    move(crow,ccol+1);
                }
                break;
            // ########## HERE #########3
            case 127:
                getyx(stdscr,crow,ccol);
                getyx(pad,prow,pcol);
                wmove(pad,crow-1,ccol);
                wdelch(pad);
                move(crow,ccol);
                break;
            case KEY_BACKSPACE:

                wdelch(pad);
                break;
            case 10:
                endwin();
                return 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}


endwin();
/*deallocate memory
 for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
 free(text[i]);
 }
 free(text);
 */
return 0;
}
```